# Question about the lattice of orthogonal projectors of *real* von Neumann algebras

Tags: von-neumann-algebras

Let $R$ be a *real* von Neumann algebra of bounded operators on the *real* Hilbert space $H$ and ${\cal L}(R)$ the lattice of orthogonal projectors in $R$.

Is it true that (similarly to what happens in the *complex* case) ${\cal L}(R)''= R$?

The problem is that the spectral decomposition is not allowable for antiselfadjoint operators in real Hilbert spaces and some of them are necessarily present in $R$. If, for instance, all of them are obtained in terms of weak limits of commutators of selfadjoint operators the answer is YES, but I am not very familiar with real von Neumann algebras.

**Addendum**

The answer is negative as it easily arises from the case of $R$ given by all of real $2\times 2$ matrices of the form $aI+ bJ$ with $a,b \in \mathbb R$ and $J$ a fixed matrix with $JJ=-I$ and $J^*=-J$. In this case, the only orthogonal projectors of $R $ are $0$ and $I$ and the von Neumann algebra generated by them is just made of the real matrices of the form $aI$. All nonvanishing antiselfadjoint elements $bJ$ cannot be included.

Nevertheless, in more complicated cases the von Neumann algebra generated by the lattice of projectors of  a given 
(real) non commutative von Neuman algebra includes some antiselfadjoint elements: the commutators of selfadjoint elements. Are there conditions assuring that these operators are all of antiselfadjoint operators of the initial von Neumann algebra?

Comment: What's a real von Neumann algebra?

Comment: The definition is the same as for the complex Hilbert space case: A sub unital $*$-algebra of $B(H)$, $R$, such that $R=R''$ (Here $H$ is a real Hilbert space). Exactly as for the complex case the last condition is equivalent the the fact that $R$ is weakly closed and that $R$ is strongly closed. See, e.g., Bingren Li, "Real Operator Algebras",  WS (2003).